# Panther Chrome WebDriver : Full screen?

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, symfony4, symfony-panther

In my functional test of my symfony 4 application, i use the Chrome Webdriver with PANTHER_NO_HEADLESS=1 to see what happen.

My problem is : Chrome browser starting with Debug Tool (F12) and not in full screen.
This is a problem because i want to test elements that appears only on full screen.

My test :

```
public function testMyTest()
{
    $client = Client::createChromeClient();
    $crawler = $client->request('GET', 'http://example.com/form');
    $form = $crawler->selectButton('valider')->form([
        'formField' => 'value'
    ]);

    $client->submit($form)

    // Some assertions here
}
```

Command :

```
$export PANTHER_NO_HEADLESS=1
```

Then

```
phpunit -c phpunitFunctional.xml --filter="testMyTest" path/to/FileTest.php
```

How can i start with full screen and without debug tool ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've finally found a solution.
I write it in case of someone has the same problem.

```
public function testMyTest()
{
    $client = Client::createChromeClient();
    $crawler = $client->request('GET', 'http://example.com/form');
    $client->manage()->window()->maximize();

    $form = $crawler->selectButton('valider')->form([
        'formField' => 'value'
    ]);

    $client->submit($form)

    // Some assertions here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution! Very helpful

Answer (score 1):

Also, consider the following:

```
    $size = new WebDriverDimension(1024,10000);
    $client->manage()->window()->setSize($size);
```

Comment: Can you complete your answer please? which namespace did you used? Do we need an additional library for this?